# How to convert a matrix containing a non-demosaiced image to a RAW image file, openable by Lightroom?

Tags: image, matlab, tiff, lightroom, dng

I have a camera module, from which I am reading out "RAW", non-demosaiced image data (this camera module uses a Bayer BGGR filter). I am currently storing this in a MATLAB matrix. I am aware that MATLAB can demosaic this image for me, but I would like to use Adobe Lightroom's demosaicing algorithm and processing tools.

Do any tools exist to convert this matrix (using MATLAB or otherwise) into a standard RAW file, such as Adobe's DNG format? I understand that DNG is very similar to TIFF, can this be leveraged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, you can use the Adobe DNG SDK. Download Adobe DNG SDK from [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/dng/dng_sdk.html).

1. Adboe DNG SDK can read dng format and save dng as tif format.
2. If you want to read bayer format( non-demosaiced image data ), you can try to hack Adobe DNG SDK. Replace of bayer data before demosaic.

Something need to notice.

1. You must use correct "bayer type"( BGGR , RGGB.. etc ).
2. You must use correct "bits per sample".
3. You must use correct "width" and "height".